# C# Перенос данных с одной таблицы в другую циклом

Tags: c#, datagridview

Сделал перенос для каждой ячейки,все прекрасно работает и вот задумался....а можна ли циклом? но нужно чтобы строка 4,5 с dvg1 заносилась в колонку 4.
Пример как я сделал показан ниже.

```
dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value);
dataGridView2.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[3].Value);
dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[3].Value);
dataGridView2.Rows[1].Cells[2].Value = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[3].Value);
dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[4].Value = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[4].Cells[3].Value);
dataGridView2.Rows[1].Cells[4].Value = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[5].Cells[3].Value);
dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[6].Cells[3].Value);
dataGridView2.Rows[1].Cells[3].Value = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[7].Cells[3].Value);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    int col = i / 2 + 1;
    col = col == 3 ? 4 : (col == 4 ? 3 : col);

    dataGridView2.Rows[i % 2].Cells[col].Value = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
}
```